# how to create tables in HTML which support all (IE, safari ,firefox) browsers?

Tags: html

table row background color supports in IE but not in safari

Comment: *(reference)* ["row bgcolor is now deprecated, and is highly presentational in its nature. The desired visual effects can all be achieved with CSS and, as such, this attribute shouldn’t be used"](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/tr/bgcolor) - it still has full support across all browsers though

Comment: I disagree with the close nazis... just because English is broken doesn't mean that it's not a question. The OP can't figure out how to set a background color... why is that not a real question (as noobie as it is)?

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
 <table id="mytable">
   <thead> <!-- Optional -->
      <tr>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot> <!-- Optional -->
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
 </table>
```

CSS:

```
 table#mytable { background-color: #004455; }
```

You can also use inline styles, but I'm not going to recommend them because it sounds like you need to learn how to do things the right way before you're allowed to make a call on doing them the wrong way.

Comment: That would color the table, not the table rows

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr class="color_red">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="color_green">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table

<style>
tr.color_red
{
    background-color:red;
}

tr.color_green
{
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually i got the answer.